# Homestead and NGINX error: emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header"

Tags: laravel, nginx, homestead

I'm trying to add a location block to the default config of NGINX. I've duplicated the homestead/scripts/site-types/laravel.sh and added the code block below:

```
location ^~ /mysocket {
    #your proxy directives
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:1234;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy false;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

As result:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header" directive
```

Whole code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A params=$6       # Create an associative array
declare -A headers=${9}    # Create an associative array
declare -A rewrites=${10}  # Create an associative array
paramsTXT=""
if [ -n "$6" ]; then
   for element in "${!params[@]}"
   do
      paramsTXT="${paramsTXT}
      fastcgi_param ${element} ${params[$element]};"
   done
fi
headersTXT=""
if [ -n "${9}" ]; then
   for element in "${!headers[@]}"
   do
      headersTXT="${headersTXT}
      add_header ${element} ${headers[$element]};"
   done
fi
rewritesTXT=""
if [ -n "${10}" ]; then
   for element in "${!rewrites[@]}"
   do
      rewritesTXT="${rewritesTXT}
      location ~ ${element} { if (!-f \$request_filename) { return 301 ${rewrites[$element]}; } }"
   done
fi

if [ "$7" = "true" ]
then configureXhgui="
location /xhgui {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /xhgui/index.php?\$args;
}
"
else configureXhgui=""
fi

block="server {
    listen ${3:-80};
    listen ${4:-443} ssl http2;
    server_name .$1;
    root \"$2\";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    $rewritesTXT
    
    location / {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
        $headersTXT
    }

    location ^~ /mysocket {
        #your proxy directives
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:1234;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy false;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
    }
    
    $configureXhgui

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/$1-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php$5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
        $paramsTXT

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/$1.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/$1.key;
}
"

echo "$block" > "/etc/nginx/sites-available/$1"
ln -fs "/etc/nginx/sites-available/$1" "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/$1"
```

Can someone spot the error I'm making? When I remove the the 'location' block the code is working fine. This code is also running on a live server without any problemen.

Comment: what is the output of `nginx -t`, which line does it say is giving the error? Also I would try with `proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy "false";`

Comment: @TarunLalwani When I run `nginx -t` I'm getting the same error. I tried changing `false` to `"false"` but that didn't seems to work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that I did not escape the variables inside the new block.

```
location ^~ /mysocket {
    #your proxy directives
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:1234;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host \$http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy false;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use a semicolon (;) at the end of each line. For example following code has error:

```
 proxy_set_header Content-Type "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
 proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
```

but this is correct:

```
 proxy_set_header Content-Type "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
 proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use docker,this error seems to be caused by replacing the '$' mark when converting the environment variable in the nginx.conf configuration file. Therefore, before replacing the environment variable, declare the environment variable DOLLAR=$ and fill in the declared 'DOLLAR' environment variable in the code sentence of the nginx configuration file that requires the $ mark.
For example,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ${DOMAIN};

    location / {
       return 301 https://${DOLLAR}host${DOLLAR}request_uri;
    }
}
```

---

Originally,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.kro.kr;

    location / {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Good luck